# How to center a windows program on the screen? (Windows XP)

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Is there a hotkey or something to center a program?  Like say I open a new Notepad session, it tends to open around the bottom left corner.  Is there a way to center it on the screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Install [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) and load this script:

```
#c::
  WinGetActiveStats Title, Width, Height, X,Y
  WinMove, %Title%,, (A_ScreenWidth-Width)/2, (A_ScreenHeight-Height)/2
```

The #c means "Windows Key + c", so this defines an action which will center the current (active) window when you press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. You could of course use some other keyboard shortcut if you prefer.